# Single scroll (left and right) website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code that makes up my website - http://jsfiddle.net/XhgPk/

How would I be able to make it so that the different colored `div` sections display inline with each other rather than jumping up and down because of the content?

--

**Answer:** http://jsfiddle.net/YpEuN/

Comment: You can add `vertical-align:top;` to `.horizontal`. I honestly don't know how reliable that is, though, hence me posting it as a comment. (I would likely have used a very different way of creating this type of layout).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add **vertical-align: top;** to your .horizontal class.

Answer (score 0):

height problem...  you can write a little jquery function to adjust li elements' height accrding to the ul's height which should be the highest li element's height.